# They don't even know where to start

Tags: discussion, questions, new-users

I have new found privileges on Stack Overflow and review many first-time questions. Many questions are what the community would call low-quality. Common type of questions are: "I want to create this like on this website."

I find myself commenting very often: "Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why don't you try yourself first and when you get stuck, please come and ask a more specific question". Or some other people would comment: "Why don't you google it first". Or I would flag the question as 'not on topic' or 'too broad'.

But I am starting to realize, many of those people are so new to programming, they don't have a clue where to start. Or they don't even know what to Google, or what they're even looking for.

This question is a good example:
*[Dynamically reordering DIV elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403011/how-to-make-a-div-located-at-the-bottom-of-html-page-to-move-to-other-html-page)*

So are we supposed to turn those people away?

Shouldn't there be a way to help total newbies?

Comment: *"Shouldn't there be a way to help total newbies?"* - there is, it's called **tutorials**. SO is for professionals and enthusiasts, people who *"don't even know what to Google, or what they're even looking for"* aren't really in the constituency.

Comment: :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403142/noobie-looking-for-someone-to-convert-vb-section-of-code-to-c

Comment: :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403482/error-while-using-operator-in-c

Comment: :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402906/why-the-second-strcpy-in-my-code-causes-stop-working

Comment: :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402686/calculating-average-of-user-inputted-numbers

Comment: @MartinJames Have a heart... We can't leave users with problems that "causes stop working", can we?

Comment: The proposed [Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) feature may help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have yet to see a novice who read a tutorial and then actually understood something. Tutorials are for quick wins, novices need to take their bloody time.

Comment: @Gimby that's fair enough, but if they can't write good questions (or figure out how the existing ones address their issue) they can take it somewhere else. SO can't be everything for everyone.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Lets hope the mentioned documentation feature will be that "somewhere else" eventually. Until then, SO will have a lot of "Welcome to Stackoverflow" to dish out, to people who run here after having been exposed to one of the net's many wonderful tutorials written by people inexperienced in conveying information :/

Comment: This is an inevitable result of a site "for all your programming questions and answers" becoming so popular.

Comment: i want to make a website lk google that indexes websites and you can use it 2 find stuff on these websites i am a total n00b kek and have no idea where to start pls give me links to tutorials or hints please do the needful thanks

Comment: @will you go to google.com. Duh. BTW: the inclusion of "do the needful" is hilariously spot on.

Answer (score 48):

> So are we supposed to turn those people away?

Yes.  (Well, more specifically, we're supposed to turn these questions away.  If those users are able to ask an on topic quality question, then it's welcome, regardless of how new they are.)

> Shouldn't there be a way to help total newbies?

That's exactly what intro tutorials, books, classes, etc. are for.  It's not what SO is for.

Comment: Indeed. SO are explicitly for professional/enthusiast _programmers_. The definition of a programmer is a person who can program in at least one programming language.

Comment: @Lundin That leaves the definition of "can program" open, which arrives us back at the OP. If we take the strictest view of your meaning, then their would be nobody on stack overflow because all programmers would know all they needed to already!

Answer (score 8):

> So are we supposed to turn those people away?

No, but if we keep closing their appallingly terrible questions, they will hopefully either leave of their own accord, or step up their asking skills.

> Shouldn't there be a way to help total newbies?

I was a total newbie once, before the Internet was A Thing. You know what I did to stop being a newbie? Bought coding books (you know, that paper stuff) and practiced. AKA **made the effort**. Generations of people before the Internet have done the same.

If your programming question is fundamental, someone else will have asked it before you, and the answer will be online. Given that, I feel personally insulted when I come across a SO question that Google can solve.

I'm not a religious man, but God helps those who help themselves.

Comment: I'm joining your church, although I would advise eBooks in this day and age. For tech stuff they're just marvelous.